# How to filter a SparkR DataFrame

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

In SparkR I have a DataFrame `data` that contains `user`, `act` and the `time` for each act. `act` contains numbers from 1 to 9, meaning we have 9 acts.

```
head(data)
```

then gives

```
user  act  time
21      1  2012-01-05
14      8  2013-05-04
21      1  2013-01-04
84      4  2012-02-02
```

For each `user`  I want to get all `act` from the first 60 days.

For example user 21 `filter(data, data$user==21)`

have these acts

```
user   act   time
21     1     2012-01-05
21     1     2013-01-04
21     7     2013-01-05
```

Here I only want the first act since the other two act's are more than 60 days old.

I can find the birth of each user (the first time an `act` appears) by this code

```
userbirth <- groupBy(data, data$user) %>% agg(min(data$time))
```

but I can't find out how to get a new dataset only containing `act` for the first 60 days for each `user`.

I try solve the problem this way

```
g <- groupBy(data, data$user)
result <- agg(g, data$time < min(data$time) +60 )
```

But R gives me an error-message: "returnstatus==0 is not True." How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close with `userbirth`; you just need to include this new `min(time)` column to your initial DF using `join`.

Here is a fully reproducible example, adding some more records to the ones you show in order to get a clear demonstration:

```
library(magrittr)

user <- c(21, 14, 21, 84, 21, 21, 14, 14)
act <- c(1, 8, 1, 4, 7, 9, 1, 3)
time <- c("2012-01-05", "2013-05-04", "2013-01-04", "2012-02-02", "2013-01-05", "2012-02-10", "2013-05-20", "2013-07-10")

df_local <- data.frame(user, act, time)
df_local
#   user act       time
# 1   21   1 2012-01-05
# 2   14   8 2013-05-04
# 3   21   1 2013-01-04
# 4   84   4 2012-02-02
# 5   21   7 2013-01-05
# 6   21   9 2012-02-10
# 7   14   1 2013-05-20
# 8   14   3 2013-07-10

df <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, df_local)

df$time <- to_date(df$time)
df$user <- cast(df$user, "integer")
df$act <- cast(df$act, "integer")
df
# DataFrame[user:int, act:int, time:date]

userbirth <- groupBy(df, df$user) %>% agg(min(df$time))
names(userbirth) <- c("user_", "min_time")  # works, although undocumented!
userbirth
# DataFrame[user_:int, min_time:date]
showDF(userbirth)
# +-----+----------+
# |user_|  min_time|
# +-----+----------+
# |   84|2012-02-02|
# |   14|2013-05-04|
# |   21|2012-01-05|
# +-----+----------+    

df2 <- join(df, userbirth, df$user == userbirth$user_) 
showDF(df2)
# +----+---+----------+-----+----------+
# |user|act|      time|user_|  min_time|
# +----+---+----------+-----+----------+
# |  84|  4|2012-02-02|   84|2012-02-02|
# |  14|  8|2013-05-04|   14|2013-05-04|
# |  14|  1|2013-05-20|   14|2013-05-04|
# |  14|  3|2013-07-10|   14|2013-05-04|
# |  21|  1|2012-01-05|   21|2012-01-05|
# |  21|  1|2013-01-04|   21|2012-01-05|
# |  21|  7|2013-01-05|   21|2012-01-05|
# |  21|  9|2012-02-10|   21|2012-01-05|
# +----+---+----------+-----+----------+
```

Before proceeding, let's check what the expected result should be based on `df2` data above:

- The unique record of user `84`
- The two records of May 2013 for user `14`
- The two records of 2012 for user `21`

Let's see (we make use of SparkR `date_add` function):

```
df3 <- filter(df2, df2$time <= date_add(df2$min_time, 60))
showDF(df3)
# +----+---+----------+-----+----------+
# |user|act|      time|user_|  min_time|
# +----+---+----------+-----+----------+
# |  84|  4|2012-02-02|   84|2012-02-02|
# |  14|  8|2013-05-04|   14|2013-05-04|
# |  14|  1|2013-05-20|   14|2013-05-04|
# |  21|  1|2012-01-05|   21|2012-01-05|
# |  21|  9|2012-02-10|   21|2012-01-05|
# +----+---+----------+-----+----------+
```

From this point, we can keep selected columns only, more or less as we would do in an ordinary R dataframe:

```
df4 <- df3[,c("user", "act","time")]
showDF(df4)
# +----+---+----------+
# |user|act|      time|
# +----+---+----------+
# |  84|  4|2012-02-02|
# |  14|  8|2013-05-04|
# |  14|  1|2013-05-20|
# |  21|  1|2012-01-05|
# |  21|  9|2012-02-10|
# +----+---+----------+
```

Notice that, after the creation of our Spark dataframe `df`, all operations are SparkR ones (and not "local" R):

```
class(df4)
# [1] "DataFrame"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "SparkR"
df4
# DataFrame[user:int, act:int, time:date]
```

Feel free to come back for any clarifications you may require...

```
sessionInfo()
# R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
# Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)
# Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
# [...]
# other attached packages:
# [1] magrittr_1.5 SparkR_1.5.1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The line df3 <- filter(df2, df2$time <= date_add(d2$min_time,60)) I do not understand. Is 'date_add' a function in sparkR ?

Comment: Indeed: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/api/R/date_add.html . I edited the text to be clear.

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to an answer outside SparkR but within R and Spark, you could use dplyr.spark.hive, a backend for dplyr. They support window functions, which is what you need here. Here is an example with the mtcars data set

```
> group_by(mtcars, carb)  %>% filter(mpg <= min(mpg) + 5)  %>% arrange(carb, mpg)
Source: local data frame [18 x 11]
Groups: carb [6]

     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
1   18.1     6 225.0   105  2.76 3.460 20.22     1     0     3     1
2   21.4     6 258.0   110  3.08 3.215 19.44     1     0     3     1
3   21.5     4 120.1    97  3.70 2.465 20.01     1     0     3     1
4   22.8     4 108.0    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1     4     1
5   15.2     8 304.0   150  3.15 3.435 17.30     0     0     3     2
6   15.5     8 318.0   150  2.76 3.520 16.87     0     0     3     2
7   18.7     8 360.0   175  3.15 3.440 17.02     0     0     3     2
8   19.2     8 400.0   175  3.08 3.845 17.05     0     0     3     2
9   15.2     8 275.8   180  3.07 3.780 18.00     0     0     3     3
10  16.4     8 275.8   180  3.07 4.070 17.40     0     0     3     3
11  17.3     8 275.8   180  3.07 3.730 17.60     0     0     3     3
12  10.4     8 472.0   205  2.93 5.250 17.98     0     0     3     4
13  10.4     8 460.0   215  3.00 5.424 17.82     0     0     3     4
14  13.3     8 350.0   245  3.73 3.840 15.41     0     0     3     4
15  14.3     8 360.0   245  3.21 3.570 15.84     0     0     3     4
16  14.7     8 440.0   230  3.23 5.345 17.42     0     0     3     4
17  19.7     6 145.0   175  3.62 2.770 15.50     0     1     5     6
18  15.0     8 301.0   335  3.54 3.570 14.60     0     1     5     8
```

In each group of cars with same number of carburetors we select all cars with a gas milage within 5 mpg of the lowest in each group.

Comment: But by filtering all groups with 3 entries is a constant. If I want to get my entries which depends on the group its must be done by making it local I assume?

Comment: A misunderstanding on my part. Please take a look at the amended answer.

Comment: So it's not possible to do in SparkR using ubuntu?

Comment: @piccolbo tweeted it already ;-) https://twitter.com/desertnaut/status/666939163741175808

Comment: Saw that. Appreciated.

Comment: @piccolbo Your package allow us to use sparkr with dplyr ? can you give us a link for a tutorial ?
 Thanks a lot for your work !

Comment: 1. package allows to use spark, not sparkR. 2. No tutorial yet but differences with dplyr are minimal. Check this dir: https://github.com/piccolbo/dplyr.spark.hive/tree/master/pkg/tests

Comment: All files but equivalence-tests.R, which is more technical, contain simple code taken from dplyr tutorials and are tested to work against spark 1.5. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will check it
Did you work with Hadley for this package ?