# Filter by Multiple Conditions with vectors

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I am trying to filter by **multiple variables** for a series of conditions using vectors on a **SparkR** dataframe.

Doing this with tidyverse on a regular dataframe is straight forward. For example:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("magrittr")

# filter vectors
filter_var1 <- c('111', '222')
filter_var2 <- c('a', 'c')

#create df
df <- data.frame(var1 = c("111", "222", "333", "333"), var2 = c("a", "a", "b", "c"))
df
# filter
df_filtered <- df %>% dplyr::filter( (var1 %in% filter_var1) | (var2 %in% filter_var2))

df_filtered
```

Attempting do something similar for a single variable filter is a little more tedious but doable (from: [sparkR example 1](https://sparkbyexamples.com/r-programming/r-filter-data-frame-by-multiple-conditions/), [sparkR example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730901/how-to-filter-a-sparkr-dataframe)):

```
library(SparkR)

# Initialize a Spark session
sparkR.session(appName = "Create DataFrame Example")

# Create a data frame in SparkR
spark_df <- createDataFrame(data.frame(var1 = c("111", "222", "333", "333"), var2 = c("a", "a", "b", "c")))

# Show the data frame
showDF(spark_df)


spark_df_filtered <- spark_df %>% SparkR::filter(., (  
  paste("var1 in ('", paste(filter_var1, collapse = "','"), "')", sep = "")
  ))
```

But I am having difficulty using AND (`&&`) / OR (`||`) statements in the case of in the same filter statement to add more conditions. I did find an example using `sparkR::subset` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625982/how-to-subset-sparkr-data-frame), but when trying to use vectors to implement the filtering I ran into issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could have used the [`%in%`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/reference/match.html) S4 method to match values in a column. And use `|` for OR, `&` for AND operators.

```
  require("magrittr")
  require("SparkR")
  # filter vectors
  filter_var1 <- c('111', '222')
  filter_var2 <- c('a', 'c')
  # create Spark dataframe
  spark_df <- SparkR::createDataFrame(data.frame(var1 = c("111", "222", "333", "333"),
                                                 var2 = c("a", "a", "b", "c")))
  # filter Spark dataframe with multiple conditions
  spark_df_filtered <- spark_df %>% 
                        SparkR::filter((spark_df$var1 %in% filter_var1) |
                                        (spark_df$var2 %in% filter_var2))
  SparkR::head(spark_df_filtered)

#>   var1 var2
#> 1  111    a
#> 2  222    a
#> 3  333    c
```